# Regulator voltage drop upon connecting a relay

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, relay

I have used an LM7805 as a voltage regulator from approx 36 V to 5 V. The regulator initially outputs 5 V perfectly but as I add up a single relay the voltage drops. And upon adding 2-3 relays in parallel the voltage further drops. Although for other types of load, the regulator works perfectly fine.

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Post a datasheet of the relays you're using, so we can know what your load actually is.

Comment: As far as I know, the input voltage you are using is beyond the absolute max input voltage of LM7805. Request you to check that for the variant you are using so that you do not damage the IC.

Comment: The relay I am using is the SRD-05V DC

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Unfortunately, this reads to me like a case of not reading and fully understanding the datasheet, instead taking it as a magic perfect voltage dropper. Read up on its characteristics and limits. It looks like you've gone over the voltage limits and possibly power limits.

Comment: @MuhammadHamzaFarooq Is there a reason you are using a 7805 linear regulator? If you need a regulator that is just about the same size, you could use a [Murata 7805SR-C](https://www.murata-ps.com/pub/data/meters/dms-78xxsr.pdf), which is a drop-in replacement but it is a switching regulator and it is rated for the high voltage input you have. (There are probably other manufacturers of the same type of thing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your relay coil requires 5V at 100mA.

All three relays will draw 300mA in total from the 7805 output.

There is a potential difference across the 7805 (from input to output) of \$36V - 5V = 31V\$. There is 300mA flowing between those potentials, for a total power of \$P = I \times V = 300mA \times 31V = 9.3W\$, all dissipated within the 7805 regulator.

Unless you have some serious heatsink on the poor thing, and a fan, that 7805 is going to roast itself to oblivion if it doesn't protect itself first. My guess is that it is going into thermal shutdown, which it does by cutting off the current path from input to output. That results in the output voltage dropping to well under the 5V you expect.

This happens in spite of the datasheet's claim that the regulator can provide 1A or 1.5A. It *can* do that, but only while it isn't shutting itself down from excessive heating.

Comment: Shall I add a resistor to reduce the voltage or adding heat sink is better option?

Comment: It's necessary to know what maximum current you *ever* expect to draw from the 7805, to be able to suggest a solution.