# Voltage regulator drop in voltage on load

Tags: voltage-regulator, voltage

[image: Here is the regulator I am using]1)I have been working on voltage regulators but they are not working correctly. I am using the LM7805 as the voltage regulator with 36V as input and 5V as output...It gave the 5V correctly without the load but as I added a 33ohm resistor the voltage dropped to zero...After that, I used an LM7812, and its output was given to a 5V regulator. The results were the same I am getting a drop...
2)Secondly I used a 10K resistors which gave the correct output but as I attached the 33ohm resistor the voltage dropped. Now even after removing the 33-ohm resistor, I could see the dropped voltage. I have to restart the circuit in order to get my output with 10k...what is the reason behind it as I am not able to understand.

Comment: I have shared the image @RohatKılıç

Comment: Was my answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/665412/292884) not adequate explanation?

Comment: @MuhammadHamzaFarooq - Hi, This seems to be effectively a duplicate of your question from about 10 hours ago: "[Regulator voltage drop upon connecting a relay](/q/665405)" where the answer *there* already explained the same problem as the answers *here*.  Please use the information from answers you receive, before asking a new question. || Please read the site [tour] & [help] to see the main site rules and how Stack Exchange differs from typical forums. Thanks. (Simon - Hi, My typing of this comment overlapped your comment. As I've included some links, I'll leave my comment visible too.)

Comment: @SimonFitch the Answer given was perfectly fine but I wanted to know that the result is still the same even after the connection of the 12V regulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I am using the LM7805 as the voltage regulator with 36V as input and
> 5V as output...It gave the 5V correctly without the load but as I
> added a 33ohm resistor the voltage dropped to zero*

An [LM7805](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm7800.pdf) produces a 5 volt output and, when connected to a 33 Ω load will supply 151 mA. If the input supply is 36 volts, the 7805 has to drop 31 volts from input to output. That means the power dissipated by the 7805 is 31 volts × 151 mA = 4.7 watts and, due to that heat being produced, the 7805 will immediately shut-down because the internal temperature of the die has become dangerously close to frying the chip.

It's a protection measure employed by the chip. You are also exceeding the maximum voltage of the input by 1 volt. You need to downgrade your expectations of such a device: -

[image]

> *After that, I used an LM7812, and its output was given to a 5V
> regulator*

It's going to be a similar story; this time the 7812 will shut-down on a power waste of nearly 3.6 watts. Maybe this time you fit a heatsink to the 7812 and just about get away with it but, you are still over-volting the input and, that's bad design.

You should be considering a much more efficient and cooler-running buck regulator.

Comment: But even when used an LM7812 with 37v input and giving its output to the 7805..then the voltage still drops...Is this also due to the heating

Comment: Yes, I was adding that to my answer as you left a comment. Same story, do the math.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum ratings must all be satisfied. 5V at 33 ohm draws 0.15A. This is well within spec.

Checking the power, 36-5=31V. This is the voltage drop across the regulator from input to output. So the power is 31*0.15=4.65W.

The regulator is overheating and shutting down. It requires a large heat sink or the input voltage must be reduced.

A better option is a switching buck regulator.